# Magento is not working in wamp server 5.4 , 32bit - Shows Internal Server Error

Tags: php, magento, wamp

I Tried to Install magento in WAMP server 5.4 , 32 bit
But every time it just shows 500 internal server error
I traced code some code and found error of
`Deprecated: Function get_magic_quotes_gpc() is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\functions.php on line 32`

Magento works perfectly on 5.3 version on wamp server with 32 bit
But how to fix this problem with wamp 5.4

Comment: yell at the magento people and tell them to stop supporting php <= 5.3, and definitely tell them to stop supporting people who insist on having magic_quotes turned on. that sort of person needs to have a printed copy of internet explorer 6's source code shoved up various orifices.

Comment: what do you mean by that? @MarcB

Comment: magic_quotes were officially deprecated in 5.3, and were a long-standing source of "zomg how could they be so stupid" complaints about PHP long before then. the best way to eliminate such outright moronic idiocies from the language is to force everyone to ditch code which try to support php 5.2 and older.

Comment: is there any php extension for that or any code patch to magento possible? @MarcB

Comment: you can turn off warnings in php, but that's not a good idea. php is properly warning about use of deprecated functions. it's magento who should fix their code, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the deprecation message is not the problem. But perhaps its better when you reconfigure your php.ini and disable it.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED|E_NOTICE)
```

You should disable the notices only to test.

I run Magento with **[EasyPHP](http://www.easyphp.org/)** and PHP 5.4.8 and have no problems. I had some problems with **WAMP** because the PHP Versions had some bugs and espacially some extensions were very buggy i don't know why. So i changed to EasyPHP which uses WAMP and its working well.

Perhaps you should download a frech version of Magento and test it with your Webserver.

But at the end your problem could have many solution. Its possible that you have a wrong line ending in a file or your **.htaccess** has a syntax error and your webserver give the message. The Internal Server errors are very hard to solve.

Comment: it is still an internal server error
however when i tried to debug it it doesn't give and warning to me in output @Stony